# PostgreSql ERROR: 22P02: invalid input syntax for integer

Tags: c#, postgresql

I'm trying to use prepared statements in PostgreSQL, but it's giving me some pretty frustrating errors.

I'm trying to select a single record from the DB, by MediaID. In the DB, MediaID is a Serial Integer. In the class structure, it's an int.

When I call sql.Prepare(), however, it's telling me that I have invalid input syntax for MediaID. I don't see how that could be the case.

```
NpgsqlCommand sql = mediaRepository.CreateCommand();

sql.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Media WHERE 'MediaID' = :MediaID";
sql.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("MediaID", NpgsqlDbType.Integer));
sql.Prepare();
sql.Parameters["MediaID"].Value = id;
```

The frustrating part is that if I set miscast the int as NpgsqlDbType.Varchar, it prepares just fine - it just doesn't return any information.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this sentence:

```
sql.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Media WHERE 'MediaID' = :MediaID";
```

Into this:

```
sql.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Media WHERE MediaID = :MediaID";
```

Note the removal on single quoted from the `MediaID` field.

Comment: When I do that, it can no longer find the coloumn "MediaID".

Comment: If you have mixed-case name, quote it but with double quotes not with apostrophes.

Comment: Does this mean I should be avoiding mixed case names with PostgreSQL? Is this convention?

Comment: This was it! Wow, that's so frustrating. Note to self: Avoid mixed case names in PGSQL.